# Jquery selector for radio button inside Jquery selector for on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have different forms that are called on click of button and I need to get the radio button selection for every form:
I am trying to get every user selection of radio button, after clicking the next button to go into the next form the query selector for the next radio button isn't called.

```js
var forms = ["topPriority", "yearsFromRetirement", "helpInvest", "comfortLevel", "married",
  "separateOrJoint", "homeowner", "recentRefinance", "numMinors", "collegeSavings", "businessOwner", "stocksTest", "testoneFourOhOne", "testoneIRA", "testoneemergencyfund", "taxExpertise", "realEstateExpertise", "insuranceProductExpertise", "sociallyResponsible", "hasAdvisor",
  "whyNewAdvisor", "location", "drivingDistance", "newQincome", "currentSavings", "saving", "advisorQuestions", "email", "username", "phone"
]

var ctSubmits = 0

var userSelections = []
var IWasSelected


$('input[type=radio][name=' + forms[ctSubmits]).change(function() {
  IWasSelected = this.value
  console.log(this.value)
});

$(".fp-button-next").click(function() {

  $('input[type=radio][name=' + forms[ctSubmits]).change(function() {
    IWasSelected = this.value
  });

  console.log("Form nr: " + ctSubmits + "Radio Selected: " + IWasSelected)

  ctSubmits++
});
```

Part of HTML File, basically it is a loop of forms.

```
<form onsubmit="javascript:funnel.next(); return false;" data-id="108" data-type="radio" class="funnel-panel js-funnel-panel radio" data-panel-name="retirementActivity" data-panel-created="1598651721000" data-panel-last-updated="1598651933000" data-panel-index="4">
   <div class="inner" style="display: none;">
      <div class="fp-question">What activity is most important to you in retirement?</div>
      <div class="inner-container"> <label> <input data-id="385" name="retirementActivity" type="radio" value="Traveling" checked=""> <span>Traveling</span> </label> <label> <input data-id="386" name="retirementActivity" type="radio" value="Spending time with family and friends"> <span>Spending time with family and friends</span> </label> <label> <input data-id="387" name="retirementActivity" type="radio" value="Pursuing hobbies"> <span>Pursuing hobbies</span> </label> <label> <input data-id="388" name="retirementActivity" type="radio" value="Working part-time"> <span>Working part-time</span> </label> <label> <input data-id="389" name="retirementActivity" type="radio" value="Other"> <span>Other</span> </label> </div>
   </div>
   <menu class="menu"> <button type="submit" value="Next" class="fp-button-next"></button> <span class="fp-button-back" onclick="funnel.back();"></span> </menu>
</form>
<div class="funnel-faq js-funnel-faq funnel_outside_container panel-why-question hidden_during_loading retirementActivity" data-funnel-panel="retirementActivity">
   <strong class="faq-title js-faq-title" data-expand="retirementActivity"> Why do we need this <wbr>information? </strong>
   <p class="js-faq" style="display: none;">This information helps your advisor matches understand the kind of retirement you envision.</p>
</div>
```

The first selector works well for the first form, when I click differnt radio button options, the value changes. After clicking the next button (class: .fp-button-next) the selector for the radio button options doesn't work anymore.

Can someone explain why this happens and how can I solve it.

I am trying to make this work on the current site: https://smartasset.com/retirement/find-a-financial-planner

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that has the relevant code (including the HTML this is working on) so that we can see what might be causing the problem and be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks for the advice, I am trying to achieve this on the current site: https://smartasset.com/retirement/find-a-financial-planner

Comment: You need to include the relevant code in the question itself... external links are fine, but only along side the code. This is because external links can change - when you fix the problem on your site, then the link doesn't show the problem any more so the question is no longer valid or useful to future users of the site.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I understand, the form part is 500 lines of code, but I will put it here then.

Comment: No, you just need to include enough code to show the problem. See how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @FluffyKitten Oh I understand, thanks for the advice, I put one of the forms, because basically there are 32 forms, where the only difference is the name and the radio button name and choices.

Comment: There's a typo in your selector `$('input[type=radio][name='+forms[ctSubmits])` - missing `]`

Comment: You probably want `ctSubmits++` *before* you wire the event handler, otherwise it's always the *previous* form.  Note that you're not clearing the old event handler so you might as well do `$('input[type=radio]')..` once

Comment: You have a `console.log(this.value)` in the first event handler, why not add a 2nd `console.log("2", this.value)` in the 2nd event handler, then you'll be able to see what's going on better

Comment: Basically it is skipping the selector inside the button click event and making the:

**console.log("Form nr: " + ctSubmits + "Radio Selected: " + IWasSelected)**
without selecting the radio selected value. I don't understand why it is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your comments I continued to improve the solution until I got a working one:

Thanks everyone that gave me some help :)

```
var forms = ["topPriority", "yearsFromRetirement",
 "helpInvest", "retirementActivity", "retirementVision", "incomeExpectation", "health",
  "comfortLevel", "married",
 "separateOrJoint", "homeowner", "recentRefinance", 
 "numMinors", "collegeSavings", "businessOwner", "stocksTest"
 , "testoneFourOhOne", "testoneIRA", "testoneemergencyfund", "taxExpertise", 
 "realEstateExpertise", "insuranceProductExpertise", "sociallyResponsible", "hasAdvisor",
 "whyNewAdvisor", "location", "drivingDistance", "newQincome", "currentSavings",
  "saving", "advisorQuestions", "loading", "email", "username", "phone"]

var ctSubmits = 0

var userSelections = []
var IWasSelected
var defaultValue = null

IWasSelected = $('input[type=radio][name='+forms[ctSubmits]+']:checked').val()


$('input[type=radio][name='+forms[ctSubmits]+']').change(function() {
   IWasSelected=this.value
   console.log("Entered first: "+this.value)
});



$( ".fp-button-next" ).click(function() {
   console.log("I will go into array "+IWasSelected)
   userSelections.push(IWasSelected)
   ctSubmits++

   IWasSelected = $('input[type=radio][name='+forms[ctSubmits]+']:checked').val()

   console.log("Button clicked")

   $('input[type=radio][name='+forms[ctSubmits]+']').change(function() {
   IWasSelected=this.value
   console.log("Entered second: "+this.value)

   });

   console.log("All selections:"+userSelections)

});
```